# Fortran 77 handling C++ memory allocations

Tags: c++, g++, memory-management, gfortran, fortran77

I'm trying to write a C++ program that utilizes a few tens of thousands of lines of Fortran 77 code, but running into some strange errors. I'm passing three coordinates (x,y,z) and the address of three vectors from C++ into fortran, then having fortran run some computations on the initial points and return results in the three vectors.

I do this a few hundred times in a C++ function, leave that function, and then come back to do it again. It works perfectly the first time through, but the second time through it stops returning useful results (returns nan) for points with a positive x component.

Initially it seems like an algorithm problem, except for three things:

1. It works perfectly the first 200 times I run it
2. It works if I call it from fortran and eliminate C++ altogether (not viable for the final program)
3. I've tried adding print statements to fortran to debug where it goes wrong, but turns out if I add print statments to a specific subroutine (even something as simple as PRINT *,'Here'), the program starts returning NaNs even on the first run.

This is why I think it's something to do with how memory is being allocated and deallocated between C and fortran function/subroutine calls. The basic setup looks like this:
C++:

`void GetPoints(void);`

extern"C" 
{
void getfield_(float*,float*,float*,float[],float[],float[],int*,int*);
}

int main(void)
{
GetPoints(); //Works
GetPoints(); //Doesn't
}

void GetPoints(void)
{
float x,y,z;
int i,n,l;
l=50;
n=1;
x=y=z=0.0;
float xx[l],yy[l],zz[l]
for(i=0;i`<`l;i++)
  getfield_(&x,&y,&z,xx,yy,zz,&n,&l);
//Store current xx,yy,zz in large global array
}

Fortran:

      `SUBROUTINE GETFIELD(XI,YI,ZI,XX,YY,ZZ,IIN,NP)
      DIMENSION XX(NP),YY(NP),ZZ(NP)
      EXTERNAL T89c
      T89c(XI,YI,ZI,XX,YY,ZZ)
      RETURN
      END

     !In T89c.f
      SUBROUTINE T89c(XI,YI,ZI,XX,YY,ZZ)
      COMMON /STUFF/ ARRAY(100)
     !Lots of calculations
     !Calling ~20 other subroutines
      RETURN
      END`

Do any of you see any glaring memory issues that I'm creating? Perhaps common blocks that fortran thinks exist but are really deallocated by C++? Without the ability to debug using print statements, nor the time to try to understand the few thousand lines of someone else's Fortran 77 code, I'm open to trying just about anything you all can suggest or think of.

I'm using g++ 4.5.1 for compiling the C++ code and final linking, and gfortran 4.5.1 for compiling the fortran code.

Thanks

### **Edit:**

I've tracked the error down to some obscure piece of the code that was written before I was even born. It appears it's looking for some common variable that got removed in the updates over the years. I don't know why it only affected one dimension, nor why the bug was replicatable by adding a print statement, but I've eliminated it nonetheless. Thank you all for the help.

Comment: Is `l` supposed to be uninitialised? And this isn't really C++ - arrays created on the stack in C++ must have their size specified at compile time, not via a variable - you are using a C/g++ extension. But I don't think that's your problem.

Comment: Ah, sorry, that should be initialized (and is in the real code). I've tried initializing with an integer size too with no changes.

Comment: Are you positive you've compiled the Fortran to use C-style function call protocol?  Fortran77 has no inherent concept of a stack.

Comment: I'm not positive of that. Is there a specific compile flag for that? I have -lg2c, but that was because it complained if I didn't, I'm not entirely sure what all it covers.

Comment: I've been out of Fortran for longer than gfortran exists.  However, it looks like Section 7.1.4 of the current gfortran manual might apply.  Use the BIND(C) attribute?

Comment: I've tried binding all of the variables directly passed in and out of C to C types with no luck. I don't know if I need to do this with the common blocks, since C never uses them, but if C needs to have them declared to avoid deallocating their memory I can try it.

Comment: 1. Have you tried a debugger? 2. Did you compile the fortran code with all runtime-checks enabled (`-fcheck=all`)?

Comment: The -fcheck=all didn't change anything, and I can see exactly where it goes wrong in gdb, but I have no idea why. One subroutine sends proper x,y, and z coordinates, and the other subroutine shows them coming in as -nan.

Answer (score 0):

You may be running into the "off-by-one" error.  Fortran arrays are 1-based, while C arrays are 0-based.  Make sure the array sizes you pass into Fortran are not 1 less than they should be.

### Edit:

I guess it looks right...  Still, I would try allocating 51 elements in the C++ function, just to see what happens.

By the way `float xx[l];` is not standard.  This is a gcc feature.  Normally you should be allocating memory with `new` here, or you should be using `std::vector`.

Also, I am confused by the call to `getfield_` in the loop.  Shouldn't you be passing `i` to `getfield_`?

Comment: But a C array declared 
float XX[50]
Should be the same as a fortran array declared 
DIMENSION XX(50)
Shouldn't it?

Comment: To answer the edit: trying 51 points didn't change anything. As for the loop, I'm just not showing the part where I use the values returned. But yes, the returned values do depend on i (or more accurately, the initial x,y, and z depend on the current iteration and some mathematical convolution, but I left it out for ease of reading)

Comment: The next thing to check would be that large global array you have there

Comment: The global array is never seen by Fortran, and what's sent into Fortran is in no way dependent on the global array. It's just there to store results, and the results are bad before they even make it back to C++.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare `XX`, `YY` and `ZZ` as arrays also in the subroutine `T89c` as follows:

```
REAL*4 XX(*)    
REAL*4 YY(*)    
REAL*4 ZZ(*)
```

C/C++ should in general never deallocate any Fortran common blocks. These are like `structs` in C (i.e. memory is reserved at compile time, not at runtime).

For some reason, gfortran seems to accept the following in `T89c` even without the above declarations:

```
print *,XX(1)
```

during compilation but when executing it I get a segmentation fault.

Comment: I frequently allocate `struct`s in C at runtime, so your statement seems unclear.

Comment: Since the real project uses over 100 subroutines, and they're all using implicitly declared variables, would I be able to do this only at the C-Fortran link? Because I tried that with no luck.